# In XULRunner, HTML5 datalist doesn't popup/function

Tags: iframe, xul, xulrunner, html-datalist

**Context:** An iframe in a barebones XULRunner (*) application contains the (validating) HTML5 document below.

**The Problem:** The datalist doesn't function - it doesn't pop-up to present filtered options, it doesn't interact with the text input - indeed there's no evidence that the datalist is doing anything at all. When the HTML5 document is viewed directly in Firefox/Opera it functions as expected - [as per this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmMpn/3/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Datalist Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="." method="get">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Datalist Test Form</legend>
                <input type="text" name="test" list="id1" placeholder="Type 'H' here">
                <datalist id="id1">
                    <option value="Bream">Bream</option>
                    <option value="Cod">Cod</option>
                    <option value="Dover Sole">Dover Sole</option>
                    <option value="Haddock">Haddock</option>
                    <option value="Halibut">Halibut</option>
                    <option value="Herring">Herring</option>
                    <option value="Mackerel">Mackerel</option>
                    <option value="Salmon">Salmon</option>
                    <option value="Trout">Trout</option>
                    <option value="Whiting">Whiting</option>
                </datalist>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Guesswork:** I'm suspecting that either datalists aren't implemented in XULRunner or that a `<popup>` workaround is required in the XUL itself. Assuming the latter I've not found any documentation specific to datalist and all guesses to-date have been unsuccessful, i.e. in the XUL:

```
<popupset>
    <popup id="datalistpopup" type="datalist"/>
</popupset>
```

with the iframe specified thus:

```
<iframe id="datalisttest" flex="1" type="content" src="..." datalist="datalistpopup"/>
```

Any guidance appreciated!

(* = XULRunner versions 28 and 30)

Answer (score 0):

Markup the iframe with the following attribute:

```
<iframe type="content-primary">
```

**References**

- [XUL: iframe Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/iframe#Attributes)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me. However, my context is also one of multiple dynamically-added iframes where none is more primary than the other (NB: the type attribute is set before the iframe is added to the document as per the warning in your link).